# What's the recommended location to get and set the Cache code ? Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

## **What I am doing ?**

Below is the code to get and set the data in cache

```
\Cache::put('Categories', $Categories, 60);
\Cache::forget('Categories');
```

## **Question**

What's the recommended location to get and set the Cache code ? So far I did this in the Controller file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **[Laravel 5.1 Cache](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/cache)** especially **Cache Usage** part, where you `set` or `get` cache depending to you and workflow of your app.

I recommended to use them inside controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Like with most of the questions of *Where Do I Put X* the answer is it depends. There is absolutely nothing wrong with doing it in your controller if your doing a small application and maybe only caching a few things.

If your writting a really big application or something quite complexted then you could consider doing your caching via a repository see [Using Repository Pattern in Laravel 5](https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/) for some information about the Repository Pattern. If you wanted you could make use of [Laravel 5 Repositories](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository) this provides not only a clean and well documented way to implement repositories but also it has specific way of doing caching see [Cache Usage](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository#cache).